# Getting transactionid(xid) from SQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, identifier

Is there a way to get [transactionid(xid)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-locks.html) from SQL query, or from plpgsql function body?

version of PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Richard answered the question. I'd like to know ... why? It's pretty unusual to want that, and I'm wondering what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: It's rather idea, but we've got one external machine (oracle), which sends us sets of data through stored procedure. In this stored procedure those sets are parsed and then divided between many tables. So idea is to get one unique id to recognize from which set those data came from, and send back this number to foreign oracle server. txid sounds promissing bc we can connect all data from function without asking any table (seq scans or similar) and we can relate txid with logs.

Comment: Sounds pretty suspect to me, but your description is a bit too terse for me to really understand.

Comment: I need just one unique id which can I send back to foreign server and keep in local system for set of rows inserted to many different tables. since all data goes through one function - txid sounds like right way to go.

Comment: why do you think it's suspect?

Comment: Well, for one thing, transaction IDs wrap around. For another, you're abusing them for a purpose they aren't intended for. I strongly recommend using a `SEQUENCE` instead, or maybe a uuid generator.

Comment: yes, but it wraps around not especially often and we've got timestamp for every record, so it's enough. It's not intended for this aim? ok, but wal wasn't intended to support repliction, so it's not argument for me. sequence it's much more expensive, bc of IO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT

`txid_current()` is probably what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL 10 or later consider `txid_current_if_assigned()` instead. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT)

> same as `txid_current()` but returns null instead of assigning a new transaction ID if none is already assigned